# Overloading << and >> in inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators, overloading

I have class Person (first name, last name, address, age) and overloaded operators << and >> to use it with filestreams:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, Person& person)
{
  ...
}

istream& operator>> (istream& inStream, Person& person)
{
  ...
}
```

It works fine - I can read from and write to file easily, but I have added two classes inherited from Person: Student and Worker.

I wrote overloaded operators for them, very similar to those above:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, Worker& worker)
{
 ...
}

istream& operator>> (istream& inStream, Worker& worker)
{
 ...
}


ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, Student& student)
{
 ...
}

istream& operator>> (istream& inStream, Student& student)
{
 ...
}
```

Only difference are two more fields in each class. The problem is, that when I use overloaded operators with either Student or Worker it seems my compiler uses operators for person. Probably it makes hidden conversion from Student or Worker to Person, but as a result there are no those additional fields written to the file.
offstream << People works just the same as offstream << Students or offstrem Workers.
Maybe placing overloaded operators declarations for inherited classes first, and for Person later in the code would solve the issue, but i don't find it an elegant solution.

If you have some ideas how to manage with the problem above, I would appreciate.

Comment: This is likely a problem with the code where you call << and >>. Can you post some code surrounding that area?

Answer (score 12):

Two things. First, make your operators take references to const, like this:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, const Person& person)
```

To solve your problem, a common pattern is to provide your types with a protected virtual `toString` method, and have the operator just call that. You can then just overload this method in the sub-classes, and even reuse the super-class implementation if you just want to append some values to the string.

Example:

```
class Person {
// other stuff
protected:
    virtual std::string toString();
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, const Person& person)
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, Person& person)
{
    ostream << person.toString();
    return outStream;
}
```

**Edit**
Actually, I like larsmans suggestion even better:

```
class Person {
// other stuff
protected:
    virtual void print(ostream & stream) const;
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, const Person& person)
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& outStream, Person& person)
{
    person.print(outStream);
    return outStream;
}
```

This will be easier to implement than the `toString` idea, because you need no temporary `stringstream` or anything like that to build the string.

Comment: The extraction operator can't take a const reference.

Comment: Or protected members `virtual void print(std::ostream &) const` and `virtual void read(std::istream &)`.

Comment: You shouldn't need either of these. There's something else that's wrong here. If the insertion operator takes its operands by reference then polymorphism should do the work for you. Those `toString()` and `print()` functions might fit languages like Java which don't have free functions, but not C++.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Since the insertion operator is a free function, it can actually not work polymorphically. Polymorphism only works with member functions. In case you have different free function for base- and sub-classes, which function gets called is determined and fixed at compile time, depending on what kind of reference the calling code uses.

Comment: @wilhemtell, no: consider `Person *p = new Student(); std::cout << *p;`

Answer (score 4):

Most probably the code which calls the `<<` operator accesses the object through a pointer or reference to *Person*, thus calling the operator for the *Person* type. The usual way of handling this is to provide a virtual method on the parent (i.e. *Person*) class which does the writing (getting the stream as an argument), and have the `operator<<` call this method to do the work. You need to provide the `operator<<` only for the parent class, the virtual dispatch mechanism will take care of choosing the right method for the object provided.

```
class Person {
   // ...
protected:
   virtual ostream& stream_write(ostream&) const;  //override this in child classes
   virtual istream& stream_read(istream&);        //this too
public:
   friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, const Person& obj)
      { return obj.stream_write(stream); }
   friend istream& operator>> (istream& stream, Person& obj)
      { return obj.stream_read(stream); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your operators could call a virtual method. Something like this :

```
struct A
{
  virtual ~A(){}

  virtual std::ostream& Print( std::ostream &os ) const
  {
    // print what you want
    return os;
  }
};

struct B : A
{
  virtual ~B(){}

  virtual std::ostream& Print( std::ostream &os ) const
  {
    // print what you want
    return os;
  }
};
```

Then create the operator<< only for the base class :

```
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &os, const A &a)
{
  return a.Print(os);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually call a virtual function streamIn and streamOut in the overloaded streaming operators, in that way I can actually create a template streaming function that works for all classes with streamIn and streamOut functions.